# HTML CSS hover dropdown menu unexpected behavior

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

My code is supposed to realize the hover dropdown effect only using CSS. However, the transition between two lists in the menu is not fluent at all. The menu jumps from one sub menu to a main one.

I was wondering if there's any solution to this "jumping" effect.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #B3000000;//f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
/* Change the link color on hover */

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
ul li ul.dropdown {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #B3000000;//f1f1f1;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0%;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  /* Display the dropdown */
}
ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#about">About &#9662;</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Employee Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporate Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Join Our Team</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: A live example that repro's the problem would be great

Comment: get the inspiration here: http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-only-accordion/

Comment: im not clear what do you sayed, can you please explain it

Answer (score 1):

I changed your `HTML` because directly inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element, you can only have `<li>` elements and other `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements. All other tags need to be inside of `<li>`'s.

```css
nav {
    display:inline-block;
}
.nav ul {
    *zoom:1;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}
.nav ul:before,.nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.nav ul:after {
    clear:both;
}
.nav ul > li {
    position:relative;
}
.nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

.nav li ul li {
    width:200px;
}
.nav li ul a {
    border:none;
}
.nav li ul a:hover {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li ul {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.nav li ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
    -webkit-transition:height 500ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:height 500ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:height 500ms ease-in;
    transition:height 500ms ease-in;
}
.nav ul > li:hover ul li {
    height:36px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About &#9662;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Employee Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Corporate Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Join Our Team</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10153683429737621&substory_index=0&id=178395412620 
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #B3000000;//f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
/* Change the link color on hover */

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
ul li ul.dropdown {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #B3000000;//f1f1f1;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0%;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  /* Display the dropdown */
}
ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#about">About &#9662;</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Employee Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporate Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Join Our Team</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </div>
</ul>
```

```css
nav {
    display:inline-block;
}
.nav ul {
    *zoom:1;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}
.nav ul:before,.nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.nav ul:after {
    clear:both;
}
.nav ul > li {
    position:relative;
}
.nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

.nav li ul li {
    width:200px;
}
.nav li ul a {
    border:none;
}
.nav li ul a:hover {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li ul {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.nav li ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
    -webkit-transition:height 500ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition:height 500ms ease-in;
    -o-transition:height 500ms ease-in;
    transition:height 500ms ease-in;
}
.nav ul > li:hover ul li {
    height:36px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About &#9662;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Employee Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Corporate Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Join Our Team</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why? Right now it's a game of spot-the-difference.